# How to require different js files based on html file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have multiple html files:

- page1.html
- page2.html
- ...

each file uses `require.js` with `data-main="js/main"`.

```
<script data-main="/js/main" src="/js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

the `main.js` file contains `require.config({...});`. - all the config stuff I need for my application, this file should always be loaded.

Now the following: based on which html file was loaded I want to load (`requirejs`) a different js file (which also has the config from `js/main`.)

- page1.html -> `js/main.js` and `js/page1.js`
- page2.html -> `js/main.js` and `js/page2.js`

Any idea how to do this, what are best practices? This is not ECMA 6, just plain old JS where I try to modularize a big js file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, still not sure if thats correct way to do but here is how I do this. eg in `page1.html`:

```
<script>
JS_MODULE = 'page1module';
</script>
... some html

<script data-main="/js/main" src="/js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

in `main.js`:

```
//on top are the configs etc...
if(typeof JS_MODULE !== "undefined"){
    require([JS_MODULE]);
}
```